# How does google analytics track events when user navigates to other page inside one domain

Tags: google-analytics

In Google's documentation it is said that an event can be tracked in the following way:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value]);">click me</a>
```

or older version:

```
<a onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value);">click me</a>
```

I was looking with Firebug to the request that are made when a click on a link and I see there aborted request:

`http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.7.2&utmn=907737223&....`

This happens because browser unload all javascript when user navigates to a new page. How in this case event tracking is performed?

**Edit:**
Since one picture can be worth a thousand words...
[image]

When I click a link firebug shows me this sequence of requests (here are shown first four, after follows requests to fill page content)

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you mean regarding it being an aborted request? That utm.gif looks like the start of a properly formed gif hit. Are you saying Firebug says that it doesn't successfully hit the gif?

Comment: @yc - No. I uploaded the picture of what firebugs shows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that there isn't enough time for the script to finish running before the user is taken to the next page.  What you can do is create a wrapper function for your GA code and in the onclick, call the wrapper function and after the GA code is triggered in your wrapper function, set a time out and update location.href with the link's url.  Example:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="wrapper_function(this,'category', 'action', 'opt_label', 'opt_value');return false;">click me</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function wrapper_function(that,category,action,opt_label,opt_value) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, opt_label, opt_value]);
  window.setTimeout("window.location.href='" + that.href + "'", 1000);
}
</script>
```

code will vary a bit based on your link but hopefully you get the idea - basically it waits a little bit before taking the user to the target url to give the script some time to execute.

**Update:**
This answer was posted several years ago and quite a lot has happened since then, yet I continue to get feedback (and upvotes) occasionally, so I thought I'd update this answer with new info. This answer is still doable but if you are using Universal Analytics then there is a [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) function available. The [`hitCallback` function is also available to their traditional `_gaq` (ga.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743105/google-analytics-hitcallback-event-tracking-not-working/22747401#22747401) but it's not officially documented.

Comment: amazing, i just had this problem and googled this answer 58 minutes after it was answered. i love how fast SO is!

Comment: It seems to me very cumbersome. Aren't there other ways to do it?

Comment: Well you can attach the wrapper function with an event listener instead, to keep js out of the anchor tag itself. But it's still the same principle of putting a bit of a delay in before moving the user along to the next page.  This is the best solution I have found so far.  Of course I'm willing to hear other solutions.

Comment: I've always thought this was an awful way of doing things (guessing how long something will take and then waiting for it to complete), but actually here I'm warming to it - if the event fails to submit at least the user still get's their link click which is way more important than any event tracking.

Comment: one alternative I have also done is if the target page is on my site, will pop the code on the target page instead of the link onclick.

Comment: GA has a Callback for events: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback

Comment: @SamuelBarbosa this is an old answer, and a lot has changed since then. I did know about this, but didn't really think about updating old answers. But since I got a notice from your comment, I updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This problem is answered in [Google's documentation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920):

use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
    _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', ' + category + ', ' + action + ']);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    var pageTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXX-X");
    pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

This more or less the same as the answer from Crayon Violet, but has a nicer method name and is the official solution recommended by Google.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there is no error estimation. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The documentation has now been updated to include a callback so there doesn't need to be an arbitrary delay.

Comment: Yes, the doc link above has been updated, but note that it now shows for UA style code not old _gaq code (though they still provide a link to it on that page). So if you are still using pre-UA syntax you'll still need to do your own setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

As above, this is due to the page being `unloaded` prior to the Async call returning.  If you want to implement a small delay to allow `gaq` to sync, I would suggest the following:

First add a link and add an extra class or `data` attribute:

```
 <a href="xxx" data-track-exit="true">My Link</a>
```

Then add into your Javascript:

```
 $("a[data-track-exit]").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var thatEl = $(this);
   thatEl.unbind(e.type, arguments.callee);
   _gaq.push( [ "_trackEvent", action, e.type, 'label', 1 ] );
   setTimeout(function() {
     thatEl.trigger(event);
   }, 200);
 });
```

I don't really condone this behavior (e.g. if you are going to another page on your site, try to capture the data on that page), but it is a decent stop-gap.  This can be extrapolated not just for `click` events, but also form submits and anything else that would also cause a page unload.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried to send the event on the second page? In GA reports, you will want to see the event on the first page's report. So theoretically you'll have to track event BEFORE thacking a pageview on the second page. Will it work like that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try this one, it works for me. Looks like that ga doesnt like numbers as a label value. So, convert it to string.

```
trackEvent: function(category, action, opt_label, opt_value){
    if(typeof opt_label === 'undefined') opt_label = '';
    if(typeof opt_value === 'undefined') opt_value = 1; 
    _gaq.push([
        '_trackEvent', 
         String(category), 
         String(action), 
         String(opt_label), 
         opt_value
    ]);
 }
```