# Setting window.location within setTimeout on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, mobile-safari, settimeout

Within a setTimeout, I am setting the location of a newly opened window.  To [avoid the pop-up blocker](http://theandystratton.com/2012/how-to-bypass-google-chromes-javascript-popup-blocker), the window is opened with a temporary local URL, and then location is changed to the target URL.  This works fine on all desktop browsers including Safari.

However, **in Mobile Safari, the location of the new window is not updated until the user returns their focus to the originating window** i.e. the temporary page is left sitting there.

This is what the relevant bit of the JavaScript/jQuery looks like:

```
var self = $(this);
if (self.is("a")) {
    var clickEventHandler = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (self.attr("target")) {
            var newWindow = window.open('loading.htm',self.attr("target"));
            var externalURL=self.attr("href");
            setTimeout( function() { newWindow.location=externalURL; }, 100 );
        }
    }
    $(this).bind("click", eventHandler);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this within `setTimeout`?

Comment: I'd guess that mobile Safari defers `setTiemout` until focus is returned. What happens for you do `document.body.innerHTML += new Date().toLocaleString()` in a `setTimeout`? What time does it report when you return from a different window?

Comment: @Michael-Mior This approach is needed because I am tracking the event in Google Analtyics, and this will not work without introducting a short delay, [see this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823489/how-does-google-analytics-track-events-when-user-navigates-to-other-page-inside)

Comment: @apsillers yes, exactly that.  I tried your test, and it reports the time that I returned to the original window.  I'll put a test page up publicly somewhere.

Comment: Apparentely, this is a [known problem with Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795864/pagehide-event-on-imminent-tab-switching-in-mobile-safari-does-not-fire-when-run)

Comment: There are some [test pages for this problem linked in a related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977170/ios-5-pauses-javascript-when-tab-is-not-active)